# Qt openGL es2 glBindTexture failed when picture size is large

Tags: qt, opengl-es, texture2d

I use Qt 4.7 whith openGL es2 , the hardwar is powervr ,sdk is sgx 4.8

```
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, bindTexture(m_myPixmapOfPic, GL_TEXTURE_2D));
```

When picture size is 512*256, it works well.When picture is 768*512, shows black which means failed.I try to find interface and increase the size of buffer of texture.But Qt doesnot support such interface.OpenGL es2 interfaces also do not mention this problem.

```
   QVector<QVector3D> vertices.append
   QVector<QVector2D> texCoords.append

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, bindTexture(m_myPixmapOfPic, GL_TEXTURE_2D));

GLSL:gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, v_texcoord) //simple bind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not due to buffer size. You may need to specify a power-of-two (ie 2^n - 2,4,16,32,64,128,256, 512, 1024 etc) sized image as texture. Alternatively the HW needs to support extensions for NON-power of two.